# Python regular expression: search .txt file string

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that looks like this

```
other stuff
set fmri(custom11) "/home/this/is/a/sample_path/to_some/arbitarily/named_11/file-with-othercharacters/file.txt"
other stuff
```

I want to use Python to search that file for

- all lines with `".txt"`
- replace `"11"` with `"12"` on the  the `".txt"` lines, but only in the file path, not in the `"custom11"` string.
- I left out the looping logic, just to focus on the use of re.search and re.sub.

```py
if re.search('.txt', line):
   print(re.sub("11", "12", line), end='')
```

Somehow, the .txt is not found with the re.search. If I use:

```
if re.search('xt', line):
```

I get most of the lines containing text files, but also other stuff. How do I properly find the `'.txt'` file lines?

Also, when testing, the `re.sub` replaces `11` with `12`, but also causes `"custom11"` to change into `"custom12"`. Is there a way to change a substring in the line?

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression, a `.` signifies any single character. Use `\.`.

```
if re.search('\.txt', line):
   print(re.sub("11", "12", line), end='')
```

Comment: Thanx! What about the second part - is it possible to replace 11 to 12 only for a substring, using re.sub?